# Analytic or holomorphic extension of the ellipse perimeter function

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, special-functions, plane-geometry

Let ${\mathbb{R}^2}^+=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x>0, y>0\}$.

Let $P:{\mathbb{R}^2}^+\to \mathbb{R}$ be the function with $P(a,b)=$ $\text{The perimeter of  ellipse}\;\; \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$.

Is $P$ a real analytic  function? Is there a real analytic extention of of $P$ to whole  $\mathbb{R}^2$? Are the Taylor coefficients computed in some reference? Is there a  holomorphic function $\tilde{P}$** defined on $\mathbb{C}^2$ whose restriction to ${\mathbb{R}^2}^+$ is equal the ellipse perimeter function.

**Note:** In the case of positive answer to the latter question, it would be interesting to think to the complex interpretation $\tilde{P}(a,b)$ where are $a,b$ are two complex numbers associated to "certain"?? complex object. Some complex analogy of "Ellipse Perimeter"?

Answer (score 4):

This function was studied since Newton's time; I suppose the power series was obtained by Newton himself. It is analytic, but not in the whole
$(a,b)$ space since it has singularities, in particular when $a=b=0$. See, for example
[this file](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~eremenko/Pdf/ellipse.pdf). The answer is an explicit function, which is a special case of the hypergeometric function.

Comment: I just find this link which ensure us the function is globally holomorphic(note that we have even power of $e$. So  I do not see why it is singualr at a=b? so it is seemms that the last part of my question(the note part) is remained to discussAm I mistaken? .https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/ellipse-perimeter.html

Comment: But lets look at it againit is not holomorphic at a=? May beit is?

Comment: We also have an evident singularity when $a=b=0$.

Comment: But the origin can not be an isolated complex singularity accoeding to Hartogs theorem.

Comment: $(0,0)$ is a singularity in the REAL plane. There are many more complex singularities. It is an explicit function after all, and you can see all its real and complex singularities. I do not know what "Hartogs theorem" you are referring to but complex singularities CAN be isolated, for example $(0,0)$ for $x^2=x^3$.

Comment: It seems that we are confusing "Singularity" with "critical point", right?

Comment: @Ali Taghavi: I don't think I am confusing anything:-)

Comment: So what do you mean by $x^2=x^3$? Is  it meant $y^2=x^3$?

Comment: Yes, this was a misprint: I meant $x^2=y^3$.